Set default Content Type to list with Pnp
I'm trying to set default content type to the list. I use 3.15.0 version of PnpSp. Following is how I'm trying to create new Project and add content type to it and make it default. I only miss setDefaultContentTypeToList function.
I can't seem to get how I can make that content type default for the list. Any help would be appreciated.
    const newList = await projectService.createNewProjectScopeList();

    await projectService.addContentTypeToList(newList.Id, '0x01001F4D88F052946249AE9DAEAAC5593418');

    await projectService.setDefaultContentTypeToList(newList.Id, '0x01001F4D88F052946249AE9DAEAAC5593418');

Functions:
      public async createNewProjectScopeList(): Promise<any> {

      const newList = await this.sp.web.lists.add('TestList', 'Description of the list', 100, true);
      return newList.data;
    }
    // Assign content type to list
    public async addContentTypeToList(listId: string, contentTypeId: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.sp.web.lists.getById(listId).update({ ContentTypesEnabled: true });
            await this.sp.web.lists.getById(listId).contentTypes.addAvailableContentType(contentTypeId);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error adding content type to list:", error);
            throw error;
        }
    }

